# Project is targeting .Net framework 4.6 which is not installed

Tags: .net-framework, visual-studio-2013

...but it is.  Co-worker has installed VS 2015 (I am using 2013). He created a project targeting .net 4.6.  I grabbed the project from TFS and tried to open it, but got the following error message "The C# project MyProject is targeting ,net framework, Version=v4.6, which is not installed on this machine." .  I downloaded .net 4.6 and the targeting pack, then restarted my box.  Tried to open the project again and got the exact same message.

Am I going to have to install VS2015 or is there a better fix?

EDIT: I have the 'Targeting' pack and the below link is for a 'Multi-Targeting' pack.  I have yet to find a working link to a multi-targeting pack. Is there a difference?

Comment: You never indicated what the error message was.

Comment: The title of the post. Full message is, "The C# project MyProject is targeting ,net framework, Version=v4.6, which is not installed on this machine."

Comment: You should not use the title, to indicate what the error is, you should provide the specific error.  The title should help us find your question, so it should describe your question, and not be an incomplete sentence.

Answer (score 6):

After I installed .NET Framework 4.6, .NET Framework 4.6 Targeting Pack and .NET Framework 4.6 Language Packs it worked.

1. [Microsoft .NET Framework 4.6 (Web Installer) for Windows Vista SP2, Windows 7 SP1, Windows 8, Windows 8.1, Windows Server 2008 SP2 Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1, Windows Server 2012 and Windows Server 2012 R2](http://microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48130)
2. [Microsoft .NET Framework 4.6 Targeting Pack and Language Packs for Windows Vista SP2, Windows 7 SP1, Windows 8, Windows 8.1, Windows Server 2008 SP2 Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1, Windows Server 2012, Windows Server 2012 R2 and Windows 10](http://microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48136)